# When does matplotlib (or which matplotlib api's) automatically convert Pandas timestamps to matplotlib dates?

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib

Looking for confirmation or correction.  It appears to me, that as long as I do this:

```
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
```

then I can pass a Pandas DatetimeIndex (which contains Pandas dates of type timestamps.Timestamp) directly in as the x-coordinate for Axes.plot like this:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
           Open     High      Low    Close      Volume  AdjClose
Date
2015-12-24  2063.52  2067.36  2058.73  2060.99  1411860000   2060.99
2015-12-23  2042.20  2064.73  2042.20  2064.29  3484090000   2064.29
2015-12-22  2023.15  2042.74  2020.49  2038.97  3520860000   2038.97
2015-12-21  2010.27  2022.90  2005.93  2021.15  3760280000   2021.15
2015-12-18  2040.81  2040.81  2005.33  2005.55  6683070000   2005.55

In [5]: type(df.index)
Out[5]: pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

In [6]: type(df.index[0])
Out[6]: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

...

In [11]: ax.plot( df.index, df['Close'] )
```

and the x-axis dates work fine.  But when building a plot directly using

```
ax.add_line(lines)
```

where lines[] is a list of

```
Line2D(xdata,ydata)
```

items, (for example, as can be seen here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/blob/master/mpl_finance.py#L133-L154 ) then the xdata must already be converted to matplotlib dates (floats as number of days since 01/01/01) doing something like this:

```
xdata = mdates.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime())
```

Is this correct that the ax.plot() automatically converts Pandas dates, but the lower level APIs do not?   Or am I missing something?

---

Also, to add something to this (based on the first couple comments) ...
If I don't register the converters, I get this warning:

```
In [7]: ax.plot( df.index, df['Close'])
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_converter.py:129: FutureWarning: Using an implicitly registered datetime converter for a matplotlib plotting method. The converter was registered by pandas on import. Future versions of pandas will require you to explicitly register matplotlib converters.

To register the converters:
    >>> from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
    >>> register_matplotlib_converters()
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)

Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x12a437f98>]
```

I'm a little confused by the last line (Out[7]) ... does that mean that the code was inside Line2D when this warning was printed?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters.html says that the registration is done in matplotlib's converter list. I would imagine that the lack of conversion in `Line2D(x, y)` would not be the fault of pandas, but rather, the failure of Line2D to convert its inputs.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  `Line2D` expects floats.

Comment: @ifly6 Perhaps that is so.  Thanks for that link.  I've been having trouble finding any documentation about this (thus the reason for my question) and only noticed this by experimenting.